# How to embed GWT UIBinder view to RCP Jface view?

Tags: gwt, embed, jface, rcp, uibinder

We have an existing GWT based web application and Eclipse RCP based desktop application. Now I want to embed existing GWT view created using UIBinder to eclipse RCP view created using JFace. Does any1 can answer how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible at all. Unless you're talking about using an SWT `Browser` and pointing it at the GWT app.

Comment: Yes I am trying to do the same. I want to embed my gwt application into my SWT browser. do u have any idea how to achieve this?